# What does it mean X symbol between 2 names?

Tags: reading-aloud, symbols

What does it mean symbol x between 2 names? (I saw it in some places regarding to the peppermint names in Latin, for example on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peppermint) and on [this site](http://www.herbwisdom.com/herb-peppermint.html)) 
[image]

Comment: It's a guess, but I think it's meant to indicate that it's an offspring of those. This is biology typography, and probably off-topic on ELL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Technically, it's [the multiplication sign, **×**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_sign), not **x**.  It indicates a [*hybrid name*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_name), one that indicates the plant or animal is a hybrid.  The Wikipedia entry begins by saying

> Peppermint (*Mentha × piperita*, also known as *Mentha. balsamea Willd.*) is a hybrid mint: a cross between watermint and spearmint.

so the scientific name is saying "this kind of *Mentha* that we call *piperita* is actually a hybrid of other things."